# Cakephp:How can i combine my list of items to appear as one list

Tags: cakephp

Hie guys,I have a code which list diffent items in different arrays,but the problem is i want those items now to appear on a single select option.Currently my code just shows one item on the select option,when i debug its shows all the stuff.How can i make my select option show all items.The array contain data from one table.

My code is

```
   $list=$this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->find('list',
             array('fields'=> array('programme_code','programme_name'),
                   'conditions'=>array('subject_code'=>$s_code,
                                'compulsory'=>'true')));
```

In my view,the code for the select option is

```
echo $this->Form->select("ProgrammeChoice.programme_code.2",$list);
```

It shows only one select option,but i want all to be available on the options

Okay when i echo the array above i.e     $list it splits into two,and the results are as follows

```
array(
    'BACC' => 'Bachelor of Accountancy'
)

array(
    'HEN' => 'Electrical Engineering'
)
```

But me i want one array for the two courses like

```
 array(
    'BACC' => 'Bachelor of Accountancy'
        'HEN' => 'Electrical Engineering'

    )
```

How do i do it.

Comment: You really need to be more specific. How do you get the two arrays? Do they contain data from two separate tables? Is the data in the same table, but have different data?

Comment: This is odd, Cake should give you the data for the highest Model in the hierarchy and its associated models. How do you get 2 arrays with an operation that returns 1 array? Are they contained in a greater array?

Comment: Your last example is how they are supposed to come out. You could try specifying the full `Model.field_name` in the conditions and the fields, and setting the option `'recursive' => -1`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I've added some lines to merge the disparate arrays.

```
$list=$this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->find('list',
  array('fields'=> array('programme_code','programme_name'),
  'conditions'=>array('subject_code'=>$s_code,
  'compulsory'=>'true')));

/* Merge array */
$result = array();
foreach ($list as $l) {
  $result = array_merge ($result, $l);  
}
$list = $result;

echo $this->Form->select("ProgrammeChoice.programme_code.2",$list);
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution, if the array is really large this operation might take a very long time and even never complete.

Comment: @8vius: It is for a select box. If they are that large, the whole UI needs to be redone possibly with ajax and autocompletion.